# SQL: using WHERE AND instead of HAVING

Tags: sql

here's an example of a SQL statement where we use `HAVING`:

```
select column1 from table1
where condition1
having condition2;
```

isn't it the same exact thing if we do this:

```
select column1 from table1
where condition1 AND condition2;
```

what is the difference between these two?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

In your example, they should do the same thing.  But `WHERE` gets processed **before** any `GROUP BY`, and so it doesn't have access to aggregated values (that is, the results of `Min()`, `Max()`, etc. functions).  `HAVING` gets processed **after** `GROUP BY` and so can be used to constrain the result set to only those with aggregated values that match a certain predicate.

Comment: To put Daniel's answer another way, the where clause applies to all rows in the result set.  The having clause is applied to the groups created by a group by clause.  So if your group consists of column1 in your example and the conditions were on column 1, then the where is the same as the having, since a row is the same as the "group".

Comment: @Strommy: Exactly.  And if for some reason you don't want to use `HAVING`, you can accomplish the same thing by using a nested `SELECT` and using the outer `WHERE` clause to express your desired predicate.

Answer (score 6):

`HAVING` is for use with aggregates, e.g., `HAVING SUM(column1) > 200`, `WHERE` is just for the columns, e.g., `WHERE column1 < 20`.

Answer (score 5):

In your example, it is the same because you have no GROUP BY

Otherwise, HAVING is applied *after* GROUP BY which is applied *after* WHERE...

Saying that, HAVING with a simple filter (`x = 2`) is *exactly* the same as WHERE because `x = 2` only has meaning if you grouped on it. You normally use HAVING on an aggregate (`COUNT(*) > 2` for example) that can only be applied after GROUP BY

Answer (score 4):

No, they are completely different.

Having conditions are for grouping aggregate functions. They are computed after the aggregated value was computed.

Example:

```
select id, count(1) 
  from table
 where COND1
 having count(1) > 1
```

Here, the `having` part is evaluated **after** the query computed the count(1) value for each group.

Answer (score 4):

As others have (mostly) correctly stated, in SQL the `WHERE` clause is evaluated before the `SELECT` clause, therefore the result of a set function is 'out of scope' in the `WHERE` clause.

For example, you CANNOT do this:

```
SELECT Subject, MAX(Mark) AS TopScore
  FROM Exam_Marks
 GROUP 
    BY Subject
 WHERE TopScore <= 70;
```

because the column correlation name `TopScore` is not in scope for the `WHERE` clause.

Of course we could use a subquery:

```
SELECT DT1.TopScore
  FROM (
        SELECT Subject, MAX(Mark) AS TopScore
          FROM Exam_Marks
         GROUP 
            BY Subject
       ) AS DT1
 WHERE DT1.TopScore <= 70;
```

The problem was, early implementations of SQL (starting with IBM's System R) lacked support for derived tables, hence the unintuitive `HAVING` was born.

You can read the whole sorry story in [HAVING A Blunderful Time (or Wish You Were WHERE)](http://www.dcs.warwick.ac.uk/~hugh/TTM/HAVING-A-Blunderful-Time.html) by Hugh Darwen, from which I've borrowed the above examples.

Answer (score 3):

No, because having is for aggregate functions or group by clause.

For example:

```
SELECT COUNT(ID)
FROM tablexpto
where name = 'a'
having count(ID) > 1
```

The first query would not run.

Answer (score 2):

HAVING specifies a search condition for a group or an aggregate function used in a SELECT statement.

A HAVING clause is like a WHERE clause, but applies only to groups as a whole, whereas the WHERE clause applies to individual rows.

Having 
http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/07/04/sql-server-definition-comparison-and-difference-between-having-and-where-clause/

Answer (score 1):

Having only works with a group by clause and limits records after they are grouped.

Answer (score -1):

to use having you need a group by clause. you will get an error without one

Comment: Incorrect: if you use a literal value (i.e. no column names) in the `SELECT` clause and omit a `GROUP BY` clause then `HAVING` clause will be applied to the whole table (or filtered resultset if a `WHERE` clause is used`) and return either one row if the `HAVING` clause is evaluated as TRUE otherwise zero rows. Example: find whether there are any gaps in a sequence of numbers: `SELECT 1 FROM Numbers HAVING MAX(num) = COUNT(*);`

Comment: that was sneaky, does anyone ever use this in the real world? how?