# How can I "input" a count for a column where it doesn't meet the WHERE criteria?

Tags: mysql, select

First of all, I'm *terribly* sorry for the title. I really had no idea how to properly word this question. If anyone can think of better wording, please either edit it in or tell me to.

On to the question:

I have two tables. `usage_logs` and `servers`. `servers` stores all the server information required for my client to communicate with a specific server. `usage_logs`, of course, store which user used a particular server, which server, and for how long.

I need a query that selects the server information for the server that is currently being used by the LEAST amount of users.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT servers.ip, servers.serverkey, servers.port, servers.id, COUNT(usage_logs.sid) nbr 
FROM servers 
LEFT JOIN usage_logs ON servers.id = boot_logs.sid 
WHERE usage_logs.time+usage_logs.date > 1344076143 
      AND usage_logs.sid IS NOT NULL 
      AND servers.status='ONLINE' 
GROUP BY sid 
ORDER BY nbr DESC;
```

The `1344076143` can be substituted with the current time (and is, in my actual script). This query *almost* works. It's selecting a server, **but** because the other server isn't actually in use, it's not meeting the `WHERE usage_logs.time+usage_logs.date > 1344076143` criteria, and thus isn't getting listed in the output.

I need a way for it to still list that server, but I have no idea how.

Also, the `usage_logs.sid IS NOT NULL` is because I just recently started trying to improve the usage tracking, so prior to today, `sid` didn't exist.

`usage_logs.sid` is the server id, and matches up to `servers.id`.

I've been Googling the hell out of this, and have actually never even used a `JOIN` statement before, so also please don't hesitate to correct any problems you notice. I desperately want to improve my MySQL skills.

Comment: Consider changing that WHERE clause into a HAVING clause to check the condition after the aggregation

Comment: What you are doing is not a `LEFT JOIN` because there are conditions in your `WHERE` clause for usage_logs which do not allow a `NULL` value. Try moving the conditions for `usage_logs` from your `WHERE` clause to the `ON` clause.

Comment: @radashk, this is solved now, but I'm curious about what you said. I've never used a HAVING clause. Any chance you wouldn't mind elaborating on that?

Comment: @Vatev, With the answer below, is that fixed?

Comment: @Rob Yes, adding `OR b.sid IS NULL` has the same effect as my suggestion. I personally prefer to put those conditions in the `ON` clause but it doesn't really matter. Using a `HAVING` clause might also fix the problem but it is not a good idea in this case because it might slow down the query because it is evaluated after the data is read and grouped (it will result in more work for the DB).

Comment: @Vatev, out of curiosity, if I were to place it in the `ON` clause instead, how would I do that? Would it be the same as in a `WHERE` clause? Pardon me, but I've never used an `ON` clause before.

Comment: The ON clause has the same syntax (and the same effect as far as I know) as the WHERE but it has an implicit `OR xx IS NULL` for LEFT JOIN's. In your case it will look something like `ON servers.id = boot_logs.sid AND usage_logs.time+usage_logs.date > 1344076143 AND usage_logs.sid IS NOT NULL`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3159765/971459

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows are being excluded because the conditions in your `WHERE` clause are effectively filtering out rows which have `NULL` values generated by the `LEFT` outer join (since `WHERE` is evaluated after `FROM / JOIN`).

What you have to do is `OR` the conditions on the `LEFT JOIN`ed table to get either servers that have usage after a certain date ***OR*** servers that don't have any usage *at all*.

Try:

```
SELECT    a.ip, 
          a.serverkey, 
          a.port, 
          a.id, 
          COUNT(b.sid) nbr 
FROM      servers a
LEFT JOIN usage_logs b ON a.id = b.sid 
WHERE     a.status='ONLINE' AND 
          (b.time + b.date > 1344076143 OR b.sid IS NULL)
GROUP BY  a.id 
ORDER BY  nbr
```

Comment: This did the trick! Also, I was unaware I could rename the tables for use in the query that way. That makes it a lot more simple to read. Although, I needed to change `GROUP BY a.sid` to `GROUP BY b.sid`. Other than that, though, all I was missing was that OR statement? Why didn't I think of that? Thanks, man!

Comment: @Rob, make sure you're doing `GROUP BY` on the table on the left side of the `JOIN` (make sure it's `GROUP BY a.id` not `GROUP BY b.sid` as you said you were doing in your comment).

Comment: Tried that, and it didn't work either. Getting rid of the `OR b.sid IS NULL and moving the `(b.time + b.date > 1344076143)` into the `ON` clause as Vatev mentioned in the comment had fixed it completely.